# Android google drive api create and edit excel file

Tags: android, excel, google-drive-api, mime-types, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to create a new Excel file and edit it in an Android app.  I am using Google Drive android API. If I use:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

as MIME type, I can see the file on Drive and when editing it, Drive copies and converts it to its own type as a new file. So when I get this file back with my app the file is still empty.

And if I use:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
```

as MIME type, Google Drive responds that it successfully created the file but I can't see it on Drive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet is the MIME type for a Google spreadsheet, not an excel file.  You cannot currently create Google spreadsheets via the Android API (Its a mistake that it returns successful.)

If you want to create an Microsoft excel document, you want the excel MIME types: application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: I want to create a file on drive and user can Edit it on google drive, Then I want  read it from app. The file may be spreadsheet file or Excel file. Excel mime type ok, but when wants to edit it on drive,  drive Converts it to a spreadsheet file.  So when I read My file it is still empty

Comment: I don't think you can do this via the Android API right now.  You can use the rest API to import/export to a Google spreadsheet from, e.g, a csv.